Python Telegram bot
I have some problems with server.
import time
import instaloader
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def instagram_downloander(url, content_type):
    print(f"Content Type: {content_type}")

    try:
        ig = instaloader.Instaloader()

        shortcode = url.split('/')[-2]
        post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(ig.context, shortcode)

        for _ in range(3):  
            try:
                post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(ig.context, shortcode)
                if post.is_video:
                    video_url = post.video_url
                    response = requests.get(video_url)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        return BytesIO(response.content), 'video'
                else:
                    image_url = post.url
                    response = requests.get(image_url)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        return BytesIO(response.content), 'image'
            except instaloader.exceptions.TooManyRequestsException:
                print("Rate limit reached. Retrying after delay...")
                time.sleep(600) 
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Retry failed: {e}")
        print("Unable to download the post. Please try later.")
        return None, None

    except instaloader.exceptions.BadResponseException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while fetching post metadata: {e}")
        return None, None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        time.sleep(10)  
        return instagram_downloander(url, content_type) 


This is my insta.py file and
elif user_state.get(user_id) == 'instagram_post':
        url = update.message.text
        content_type = 'post'
        await update.message.reply_text("Please wait 1 minute for loading...")
        
        media, media_type = instagram_downloander(url, content_type)

        if media and media_type:
            if media_type == 'video':
                await update.message.reply_video(video=media, filename='instagram_video.mp4')
            elif media_type == 'image':
                await update.message.reply_photo(photo=media, filename='instagram_image.jpg')
            else:
                await update.message.reply_text("Unsupported media type.")
                # Credit.deduct_credits(user_id, 1)
            await update.message.reply_text(f"Download successful! \nFor using the bot again, please write /start.")
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text("Failed to download the Instagram content.")
        user_state[user_id] = None

this is my funct.py file.
When I run code on VS code and test telegram bot it work correctly. I can download reels and post. But when I run it with server (digital ocean) it not work. Why? What can problem? Thank you all
I try more library and I change IP address but it not work:(

There isn't enough information here to know exactly what your problem is. You haven't provided a stacktrace or exception, or specified whether the issue is with the bot, downloading from instagram, digital ocean, or something else.
That said: If the issue is downloading from Instagram, it's very likely that Instagram is identifying your connection as coming from a cloud provider and blocking it. Changing your IP address in DigitalOcean would not be enough, because you would need to be coming from an IP which is not a cloud provider's. Using a different library for downloading data from instagram, or even implementing it yourself, would not avoid this issue.
You would need a VPN, or at least to proxy your requests through a host that is not identifiably a cloud provider.

I checked VPN also. It not helped. And there exception not give error, it print: Failed to download the Instagram content - only.

It's possible that the issue in Digital Ocean is multiple factors at once, then.
You could investigate adding a valid (and common) user agent string for your requests.get calls in your download function; I'd recommend trying that next.
That said, you should adjust the except Exception as e part of your code to at least print the exception and its stacktrace.

a big part of the answer looks like a comment
